# Where to find a cats.NonEmptyParallel[IO,F]?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

This used to work:

```
val ioA = IO(...)
val ioB = IO(...)
val ioC = IO(...)
(ioA, ioB, ioC).parMapN((_, _, _) => ())
```

Then, about or around Cats `1.0.0-RC2`, it stopped working. Now I get

```
could not find implicit value for parameter p: cats.NonEmptyParallel[cats.effect.IO,F]
```

and I can't figure out for the life of me what I need to get it working again. Does anybody know what I need to import or pass in (I've tried an implicit `Timer[IO]`) to get this back up and running? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [RC3](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/releases/tag/v1.0.0-RC3), Parallel instance of IO [requires a `ContextShift[IO]` implicit](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/v1.0.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L834) instead of `Timer[IO]`.

You can get one from `IOApp` or by doing [`IO.contextShift(ec)`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/v1.0.0/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L1376), where `ec` is `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`

Comment: I am the other person who got an error following the same [example](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#parmapn). I find it more helpful if the instructions (bullet points) above the code snippet be a bit more clear or include `import cats.effect.IO`, `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` and  `implicit val contextShift = IO.contextShift(global)` in the code snippet. I could do a PR but I afraid I lack the knowledge to correct the whole document. Thanks